# What word best describes a behaviour in which one is boastful or proud of an attribute that most would consider undesirable?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What word best describes a behaviour in which one is boastful or proud of an attribute that most would consider undesirable? (E.g., "There ain't anyone around here dumber or fatter than me."

Comment: An *idiot*? Haha. Sorry, but....yea :/

Comment: I see an inexplicable optimism.

Comment: This would be hard to express even with a phrase.  I might call it "pretentious humility" .  This question led me into a web surfing rabbit hole looking into people using these words together, whether it is a known rhetorical device (a few come close, but not that close). I also wandered to searches to see if it is a sign of something like narcissism (there are some hits on the two words together, however none of the discussions seemed particularly worthy of citation)

Comment: 'self-deprecating' might be a simple way although it doesn't catch everything, and falls a step or two short of "boastful".  I might write it up as a qualified answer though.

Comment: "Wearing his ____ on his sleeve" is the colloquial phrase that comes to mind.  E.g., tactlessness.

Comment: "Rock" - I remeber a recent episode of the Simpsons where homer and Lenny are talking about fashion and Homer says something about Lenny's suspenders being uncool. Lenny says "I don't wear suspenders, I ROCK suspenders.

Answer (score 1):

We may use the word , "Vainglorious" which is  to mean a person of whom we are critical because he is proud of what he is or has done and boasts a lot about himself or his doings. A vainglorious attitude is not very likeable and can be annoying to be around.
An example :

- The vainglorious trainer spent more time flexing his muscles and talking tall than he did helping build his clients.

Comment: ***Vainglory*** would be the associated behavior.